# Ask user to update app version

Tags: angular, algorithm, typescript, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

I am working on an app(Ionic App) feature which is about to ask user to update the app if new version is available in store. Now I have to make decision how to implement it. I have an api(ASP.NET Web api) which returns the details about current version of app is available in app store. This API reads it from a config.

Now the question is how should I call the api to make decision i.e. to ask user to update the app.  A user should get message to update in following case provided that value in config changes for app version:

1. App is closed : when user launches the app
2. App in background: when app comes in foreground
3. App in foreground: when user is running then immediately

In short how should I go about implementing this?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more what you call "store" - App Store / Google Play?

Comment: So I would create a special API endpoint (GET) that returns version identifier from your back end, which your client app can compare with locally stored (Ionic Storage) one if there is a mismatch - you can provide user with a modal asking them to update. Now separate question is when your app queries this API. Seems like you need to do it in the end of startup cycle for the app, then potentially tie it to certain user activities on the client.

Comment: if you can afford I would recommend using Ionic Pro option for dynamic updates for your app. https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/deploy/

Comment: @Sergey: Its both apple store and play store.

Comment: @Sergey: With respect to affordability I spoke with project manager , he does not want to spend anymore lol !

Comment: @Sergey : Tying up in app cycle bootup is fine but I feel overwhelmed when I want to tie it up at user activities, but that's the option I have for now.

Comment: I see;) but you could identify "meaningful" action (like another API call that could trigger version check for example)

Comment: yes I did exactly that, made the list of all the important api calls and will hook this up there.

Comment: @Gautam How did you resolve this for iOS and Android both with ionic ?